# How to copy an image from androids apk package folder to another folder from android device

Tags: java, android, file-handling

So I want to copy an image from my android apk package folder to another folder inside that package after installing the application in Android device. And I want to do this programmatically on a click of a button from my own application.
I don't know it's even possible or not, I tried to find an online solution but got nothing. Can please someone suggests a way to do it? Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [Xplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore) app.

- Open and click on App Manager
- Click on the App and hold for 2 seconds
- Select **Open as Zip**
- Navigate to /res folder and you'll see all the other res files in there.

Feel free to accept this if it works for you.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying, but I want to achieve this programmatically not with an third party software. I want to do this in my application on button click. I think I should have edit my question and make it more clear. But again thanks for your time and amswer

Comment: Oh. You should definitely do that. Your question was quite misleading. Good luck.